# Composable arrow function example in video?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

While following a video tutorial, the host was recommending composable factory functions instead of using bind or arrow functions, but I think I've seen one issue and would like to know if I have understood properly, here is the code:

```js
const createDragon = element => ({
  breathe() {
    return `abcd efgh ${element}`
  }
})

const newDragon = createDragon('fire');
console.log(newDragon.breathe());
```

is the downside to this way over using class syntax that the newDragon object will have 'fire' set as it's element forever now and to change it, you'd have to create a new object?

Where as if it was a class instance with an element property, then you could just reassign a new value to that property, have I understood this ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using closures over the factory arguments (and providing no setter methods), the `element` is essentially a constant. This pattern is very suitable for creating immutable objects in functional programming. Not so much for classical OOP.

Comment: Thanks, is there a technique to use a setter method in this instance? Will accept answer when allowed to.

Comment: @jobe You'd just add a `setElement(e) { element = e; }` method to the object literal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Object Composition](https://medium.com/code-monkey/object-composition-in-javascript-2f9b9077b5e6)

> ***"...object will have 'fire' set as it's element forever now and to change it, you'd have to create a new object?"***

Sounds like object composition. Although an object is immutable, cranking out objects is easy using a factory function.

#### In the Following Demo:

- Factory function `summonDragon()` has an object called `dragon` which is ***like*** a `contructor()` (of course it isn't because class involves prototype) in a class:

  **class:**

  > ```
  > constructor(name) {
  >   this.name = name;
  > }
  > ```

  **factory:**

  > ```
  > let dragon = {
  >   name: name
  > };
  > ```
- [Concatenative inheritance](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-heart-soul-of-prototypal-oo-concatenative-inheritance-a3b64cb27819) is possible by [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). The object `powers` has methods: `.breath()` and `.flight()` which will be inherited by the `dragon` object.

---

### Demo

```js
const powers = dragon => ({
  breath: () => {
    const damage = dragon.element;
    switch (damage) {
      case 'fire':
        return `${dragon.name} breathes fire causing ${dragon.attack * 3} damage`;
      case 'ice':
        return `${dragon.name} breathes ice causing ${dragon.attack * 2} damage`;
      default:
        return;
    }
  },

  flight: () => {
    if (dragon.age >= 300) {
      return `${dragon.name} flies fast`;
    }
    if (dragon.age < 300 && dragon.age >= 150) {
      return `${dragon.name} flies average`;
    }
    if (dragon.age < 150) {
      return `${dragon.name} flies slow`;
    }
  }
});

const summonDragon = (name, age, element) => {
  let dragon = {
    name: name,
    age: age,
    element: element,
    defense: age * 10,
    attack: age * 15
  };
  return Object.assign(dragon, powers(dragon));
};

const redDragon = summonDragon('smaug', 761, 'fire');
const whiteDragon = summonDragon('fröst', 101, 'ice');
redDragon.breath();
redDragon.flight();
whiteDragon.breath();
whiteDragon.flight();

console.log(`${redDragon.name} - Attack: ${redDragon.attack}`);
console.log(`${whiteDragon.name} - Attack: ${whiteDragon.attack}`);

console.log(redDragon.flight());
console.log(whiteDragon.flight());

console.log(redDragon.breath());
console.log(whiteDragon.breath());
```